# The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html" - Node

Tags: javascript, html, mime, pgadmin

I'm getting this error while trying to create/import a **Client** instance to connect to a local DB, (PGADMIN).

```
import {Client} from '/node_modules/pg/lib/'
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REPDO.png)

[My Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koobE.png)

[Last part of my index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ur8k6.png)

I've tried many types of urls but I can't get it done. So I'm asking for help.

Also, I've tried: `const {Client} = require('pg')`, but I get the "**Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"**

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the error in the question itself, instead of an image.

Comment: 1) Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: 2) Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Comment: Edit the question to provide clarification, don't bury details in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here.

1. `/node_modules/pg/lib/` is going to resolve to an HTML document listing the files in that directory. You can only import a JS file.
2. Any library that allows you to directly connect to a postgresql database is going to depend on APIs provided by Node.js and which are not available in a browser, so even if you imported the correct URL, it still wouldn't work.

Connect to the database from server-side code and use it to provide the client with a webservice that you can access with Ajax.

---

> Also, I've tried: `const {Client} = require('pg')`, but I get the "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

Browsers don't have native support for CommonJS modules.